# Find all entire functions such that $|f(z)|\leq |z^2-1|$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all entire functions such that $|f(z)|\leq |z^2-1|$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$.

For large $z$ we have $$|f(z)|\leq 2|z|^2$$ so $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$. But how to continue? Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: What can you say about $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$?

Comment: We have $|f(1)|=|f(-1)|=0$, so $f(z) = C(z+1)(z-1)$. Wow, that's beautiful.

Comment: @Jolien How do you stat that $f$ is a polynomial of degree$\leq$ 2? Are you using some theorem?

Comment: @ajotatxe Yes, I use a theorem from my book: "Extended version of Liouvilles Theorem": Let $f$ be entire with $|f(z)|\leq M|z|^m$ for large $z$, for some $M$ and some $m>0$. Then $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq m$.

Comment: @Jolien : Did you finally find an answer for this ?  can you please post it as an answer below if you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|f(z)|\leq M |z|^2$ we know that $f$ has to be a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$. (Extended version of Liouvilles Theorem).
Furthermore, we have
$$
f(1) = 0 
$$
and
$$
f(-1)=0
$$
so therefore $f(z) = C(z-1)(z+1)=C(z^2-1)$ for some constant $-1\leq C\leq 1$.