# Find all entire functions such that $|f(z)|\leq |\sin(z)|$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all entire functions such that $|f(z)|\leq |\sin(z)|$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$.

Half an hour ago I asked the same question for $|f(z)|\leq |z^2-1|$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811352/find-all-entire-functions-such-that-fz-leq-z2-1-for-all-z-in-mathbb-c) but this time I cannot say something like
$$|f(z)|\leq M|z|^m$$
so I don't know how to start. The problem is that
$$
\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}
$$
gets really large if $z$ gets large.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: Look at the function

$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{\sin z}.$$

It is entire and - what?

---

Bounded. Hence constant. Thus $f(z) = c\cdot\sin z$ for some $c\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\lvert c\rvert \leqslant 1$.

Generally, if you have an inequality $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant C\cdot\lvert g(z)\rvert$ between two meromorphic functions $f$ and $g\not\equiv 0$ on a domain $U\subset\mathbb{C}$, the quotient $\frac{f}{g}$ is a bounded holomorphic function on $U\setminus S$, where $S$ is the union of the pole sets of $f$ and $g$ and the zero set of $g$. As the union of finitely many closed discrete subsets of $U$, it is again a closed discrete subset of $U$, and hence all points of $S$ are removable singularities of $\frac{f}{g}$. It is customary to consider these removed without changing the notation, and so $\frac{f}{g}$ is a bounded holomorphic function on $U$. If $U = \mathbb{C}$ (or if $\mathbb{C}\setminus U$ is "thin enough" - has analytic capacity $0$), it follows that $\frac{f}{g}$ is constant, i.e. $f(z) = c\cdot g(z)$ for some $c$ with $\lvert c\rvert \leqslant C$.

Comment: I thought about that too, but why is that entire? What is $g(0)$?

Comment: Riemann's removable singularity theorem says it's entire. What $g(0)$ is depends on $f$, but the inequality gives a bound on the modulus.

Comment: I understand, thanks.

Comment: Yes, but $f(0) = 0$ alone would not be sufficient if $\sin$ had a multiple zero in $0$. But the inequality $\lvert f(z)\rvert\leqslant \lvert \sin z\rvert$ implies that $f$ vanishes of at least the same order as $\sin$ at all zeros of $\sin$.