# Let $ f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ such that $ |f(z)| \leq |sin(z)| $ for every $ z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $   such that $ |f(z)| \leq |sin(z)| $ for   every $ z \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove  that  there  exist $ C \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|C| \leq 1$   such that $ f(z) = C sin z $ for  every $ z \in \mathbb{C}$. How  to  proceed?

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: I presume you want $f$ holomorphic?

Comment: Answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/811393, and more generally, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52121.