# Find all entire functions $f$ such that $|f(z)| \leq |\sin(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Find all entire functions $f$ such that $|f(z)| \leq |\sin(z)|$,   $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$

I think Liouville's Theorem is the way to go.

Liouville's Theorem states that:

> Every bounded entire function must be constant.

Since $\cos(z)=0$ for $z=\frac{2k+1}{2} \pi$,

my answer would be that the only entire function is the zero function $g\equiv 0$.

Am I correct?

**Edit:**
I got a little bit confused, because in $\mathbb{R}$, sin is bounded with $|\sin(x)|<1$.
Because of this I thought that I only need to search constant functions f, such that
$|f(z)| \leq |\sin(z)|$.

This is why I thought that the Zero-Function is the only option.

Considering the comments, $f(z):= a \sin(z)$ with $|a| \leq 1$ also fullfill the condition wanted.

How can I proof that these are all function?

Comment: I assume that any function $f(z)=a\sin(z)$ where $|a|\le1$ is also ok.

Comment: In general, if $f,g$ are entire functions such that for all $z\in\Bbb{C}$, $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|$, then $f=ag$ for some constant $|a|\leq 1$ (if $g=0$, this is obvious, otherwise, $f/g$ is meromorphic and bounded, so has an entire extension by Riemann's theorem, and hence constant by Liouville).  See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @PC1 Why should f(z)= a sin(z), with |a|<1 be an answer. Wouldn't Liouvielle's Theorem suggest that the functions I am looking for are constant?

Comment: @PC1 Sorry, I did missunderstand something. I edited my question.

Comment: @Andres2003 it's Liouville, not Liouvielle.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/811397/960197 answers better than I could do!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: From $\sin z=0$ we get $f(z)=0$. Therefore
$\frac{f(z)}{\sin z}$  is holomorphic.

Comment: $\sin z /z$ is not bounded.

Comment: @geetha290krm: Thanks for the heads up, improved the hint